# Can I open a Login window when someone joins wifi network?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, wifi

I would like to know if It is possible to open a login window when someone joins my WiFi network. Like a Hotspot, but I would like to program it on my own so it can be customized to my requirements.

For an example, while joining Hotspot Internet say 'Employee Hardware Store WiFi', it would open a login window to access Internet. Is is possible to create similar login page with PHP scripts and look for registered users in database, and then manage access to Internet.

Comment: Some easy googling gave me the exact answer you were looking for: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-a-wireless-internet-hotspot-at-home-in-10-minutes-for-free/

Comment: I did that User8889 but I didn't find my answer... And I also have a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for creating authorization portal for local wifi, then see this project on [GitHub by kaptk2](https://github.com/kaptk2/portal)

Comment: Thanks! This should help!